# String substring out o range

Tags: c++

I have problem with this code. I have read some questions about it but I can't find problem in my code.

```
string Mansfildenc(string input){
    string output;
    char tab[5][5] = {
        {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'},
        {'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'k'},
        {'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p'},
        {'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u'},
        {'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'}};
    char tab2[5]={'A','E','I','O','U'};
    int j=0,i;
    char c;
    int gasit;
    int lin,col;
    for(i=0;i<input.length();i++){
        c=tolower(input[i]);
        if(isalpha(c)){
            if(c=='j'){
                output[j]='E';
                j++;
                output[j]='O';
                j++;
            }
            else{
                gasit=0;
                for(lin=0;lin<5;lin++){
                    for(col=0;col<5;col++)
                        if(tab[lin][col]==c){
                            gasit=1;
                            break;
                        }
                        if(gasit==1) break;
                }
                output[j]=tab2[lin];
                j++;
                output[j]=tab2[col];
                j++;
            }
        }
        else{
            output[j]=c;
            j++;
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Help me if you can guys. I am working with Visual Studio 2010. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `output` is an empty string. As long as this is the case, `output[j]` is not valid for any value of `j`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a char[] to hold your output or use output = output + string(1,char) to append your chars to your output string.

As Luchian suggested, you need handle the char[] very carefully which also requires some changes to your code. Use string instead.

Comment: Returing a local `char[]` would result in undefined behavior.

Comment: i didn't suggest he return the char[]. It's safe to return string(char[]) .

Comment: Why not use idiomatic C++? Why not `string`?

Comment: i did suggest he can use "or use output = output+string(1,char)" . which is string